# Why can you obtain Drax pre-hardmode on mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I recently found that Drax, usually a hardmode item which requires all three mechanical bosses to be defeated in order to craft, can be obtained pre-hardmode on mobile. It appears rarely in shadow chests in the underworld.

However, it seems strange to me that this is the case, as it means that you are not required to work your way through the hardmode ores, as you can mine them all straight away.

So I was wondering if somebody was able to provide some insight into why Drax is available so early on in the game. Is it that perhaps it’s a bug of sorts, or did the developers intend for this to be the case?

Comment: The only person who could answer why a design decision was made is the developers themselves... so this question is unfortunately off-topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Note this answer isn't very officially sources.

This may have actually been intentional, as some users said [here](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/mobile-drax-in-shadow-chests.62230/). I believe so because Mobile has always given players a easier time, because controlling is difficult. Most bosses have reduced damage and HP.

The Drax in pre-hardmode is probably to give lucky or patient players a boost.